# how to filter data from XML file using user input C#

Tags: c#, xml

i am making program to preform some functions on XML file data and then display rows that has the right one to user in grid view , in my program the user can input some value like salary and the program must display all employees that have this amount of salary in table on grid view , but how i can filter the data using the user input since the ".RowFilter" takes only value that i decided before like "salary>1000"

Comment: Have you tried `XmlNodeList nodeList = root.SelectNodes(
     "descendant::user:employee[employee:salary=10]", nsmgr);`

Comment: i can't understand your code can you tell me what it mean exactly

Comment: You can read XML Files with [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) user:employee is an example path leading to every Node employee with a parent child user. [employee:salary=10]  Filters to get only those who have salary 10 ... now you have all employee nodes with a parent user and 10 salary in your nodeList, you can display this node list now

Comment: sorry but "nsmgr" stand for

Comment: its a NameSpaceManaGeR and it is for resolving prefixes in your xpath

Comment: i am sorry but you seems didn't understand my question i don' t want to decide which one to display i want the user to enter value to search for it and display it on  grid view  like what we are doing while writing in SQL to display result from data base

Comment: I dont think you understand me ... you can give the xpath something like [employee:salary=VARIABLE] let the user input the VARIABLE and then only display the node List in your gird view

Comment: i am sorry but one last question how i can by this method  showing result in grid view

Comment: @KaneDavid Offtopic ... just a final word on the question you deleted upon the close requests yesterday: I gave you an "answer". I explained to you why such a question will most likely only result in downvotes and close requests. You see, if you want to get some helpful answers for your questions, then you have to work on the quality of your input.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show a simple example of how to use RowFilter, receiving input from the user.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            //InitializeComponent();
            this.Width = 400;

            dtPersons = new DataTable();
            dtPersons.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dtPersons.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

            // Should be read from file
            dtPersons.LoadDataRow(new object[] { "John", 30 }, false);
            dtPersons.LoadDataRow(new object[] { "Smit", 35 }, false);
            dtPersons.LoadDataRow(new object[] { "Jack", 25 }, false);
            dtPersons.LoadDataRow(new object[] { "Brad", 20 }, false);
            dtPersons.LoadDataRow(new object[] { "Paul", 40 }, false);

            var dgv = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
            dgv.DataSource = dtPersons;

            tbFilterName = new TextBox { Parent = this, Top = dgv.Bottom + 30, Width = 150 };
            nudFilterAge = new NumericUpDown { Parent = this, Top = tbFilterName.Top, Left = tbFilterName.Right + 50 };

            var btnFilterName = new Button { Parent = this, Top = dgv.Bottom + 60, Text = "Apply filter by Name", AutoSize = true };
            var btnBothFilters = new Button { Parent = this, Top = dgv.Bottom + 60, Text = "Apply both filters", AutoSize = true, Left = btnFilterName.Right + 20 };
            var btnFilterAge = new Button { Parent = this, Top = dgv.Bottom + 60, Text = "Apply filter by Age", AutoSize = true, Left = btnBothFilters.Right + 20 };

            btnFilterName.Click += BtnFilterName_Click;
            btnBothFilters.Click += BtnBothFilters_Click;
            btnFilterAge.Click += BtnFilterAge_Click;
        }

        DataTable dtPersons;
        TextBox tbFilterName;
        NumericUpDown nudFilterAge;

        private void BtnFilterAge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = $"Age > '{nudFilterAge.Value}'";
            dtPersons.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }

        private void BtnBothFilters_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = $"Name = '{tbFilterName.Text}' or Age > '{nudFilterAge.Value}'";
            dtPersons.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }

        private void BtnFilterName_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filter = $"Name = '{tbFilterName.Text}'";
            dtPersons.DefaultView.RowFilter = filter;
        }
    }
}
```